# Filtering a std::set based on specific data

Tags: c++, stl, set, filtering

I have a std::set of a class which stores some master data. Below is how my set looks like:

```
std::set<TBigClass, TBigClassComparer> sSet;
class TBigClassComparer
{
 public:
 bool operator()(const TBigClass s1, const TBigClass s2) const
 {
   //comparison logic goes here
 }
};
```

Now I want to filter data in this set based on some fields of the TBigClass and store it in another set for manipulation.

```
std::set<int>::iterator it;
for (it=sSet.begin(); it!=sSet.end(); ++it)
{
  //all the records with *it.some_integer_element == 1)
  //needs to be put in another set for some data manipulation
}
```

Could anyone tell me an effective way to accomplish this? I do not have any libraries installed so solutions detailing use of boost would not help.

Update: I am working on C++98 environment.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: First look for efficiency here: If `TBigClass` really is a big class, use `const &` in the `operator()`. Taking this by value is no a good idea.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

```
struct Condition {
    bool operator()(const T & value) {
        // predicate here
    }
};
std::set<T> oldSet, newSet;

std::copy_if(oldSet.begin(), oldSet.end(), std::inserter(newSet, newSet.end()), Condition());
// or
std::copy_if(oldSet.begin(), oldSet.end(), std::inserter(newSet, newSet.end()), [](const T & value){/*predicate here*/});
```

Comment: Wow, didn't notice std::inserter before. Also, if Condition is only for one-time use, convert it to lambda.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'm still halfway stuck in C++03 world

Comment: Pretty sure `std::inserter` takes a second argument, the iterator to insert before.

Comment: @JosephMansfield You're right, it does, thanks, edited.

Comment: Thanks! I do not have c++ 11 so may be I will have to use std::remove_copy_if

Comment: @Erbureth it works like a charm :) many thanks
I am using reverse_copy_if and !Condition
Thanks again